# Print loop output horizontally?

Tags: java, for-loop

Hey guys I have to write a program for class that asks me to produce a bar graph based on how many cars a salesperson sold for the month. An example is this:

```
Pam XXXX

Leo XXXXXX
```

I'm almost there but not quite. As of right now I can get one X next to the salespersons name but any others are printed underneath on separate lines.

```
Pam X 

X


X
```

If you can help me get those other X's on the same line I would really appreciate it. Thank you for your input!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BarGraph
{
    public static int Pam = 0;
    public static int Leo = 0;
    public static int Kim = 0;
    public static int Bob = 0;

    public static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter number of cars sold by Pam ");
        Pam = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number of cars sold by Leo ");
        Leo = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number of cars sold by Kim ");
        Kim = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number of cars sold by Bob ");
        Bob = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Pam "); pamsCars();
        System.out.print("Leo "); leosCars();
        System.out.print("Kim "); kimsCars();
        System.out.print("Bob "); bobsCars();
    }

    public static void leosCars()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < Leo; i++)
        {
            printX();
        }
    }

    public static void kimsCars()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < Kim; i++)
        {
            printX();
        }
    }

    public static void pamsCars()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < Pam; i++)
        {
            printX();
        }
    }

    public static void bobsCars()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < Bob; i++)
        {
            printX();
        }
    }

    public static void printX()
    {
        System.out.println("X");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `System.out.println` prints some characters, _followed by \n_ (the newline character).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `System.out.println("X");` This automatically appends a newline character to the end of the string.

Instead use `System.out.print("X");` to print the X's next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

couldn't you use a

```
System.out.printf("%s",x);
```

as well?

or

```
System.out.printf("%n%s",x);
```

i didn't try the loop myself but i'm pretty sure one of the two would also be an alternative... the %n will give you the same result as println as long as you go with printf and %n... its the same escape sequence as \n when you're using println.

i just learned that a month ago in class, so i figured i'd share what basic knowledge i have... mid-terms next week so i have programming fever.

Answer (score 0):

use `print` instead of `println`  in your printX function to be specific.

since println prints and adds break (newline)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printX()
    {
        System.out.println("X");  // println() puts newline character.. use print()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make these changes:

```
 System.out.print("Pam "); pamsCars();System.out.println("");
```

and

```
 public static void printX()
    {
        System.out.print("X");
    }
```

As the others have said, the "println()" method adds a "\n" to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Change your printX() method not to print newline and change the printCar() signature to accept name and number of X to print.

```
public static void printX()
{
    System.out.print("X");
}

public static void printCars(String name, int num)
{
    System.out.print(name);
    for(int i=0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printX();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Now you can call them like

```
printCars("Pam ",Pam));
printCars("Bob ",Bob));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following (sorry not tested, so in principle only and more of a meansd of shjowing an alternative to loops).

Of course a flaw is that a user could input more than 10.

There again what if the user input 10,000? (*would you really want to print 10,000 X's*). Perhaps something to think about.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BarGraph
{
    public static int Pam = 0;
    public static int Leo = 0;
    public static int Kim = 0;
    public static int Bob = 0;

    public static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Assume max sales of 10
    public static final String maxsales = "XXXXXXXXXX"; //+++++NEW

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter number of cars sold by Pam ");
        Pam = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number of cars sold by Leo ");
        Leo = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number of cars sold by Kim ");
        Kim = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number of cars sold by Bob ");
        Bob = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();

        printCars("Pam",pam);  //+++++NEW
        printCars("Leo",leo);  //+++++NEW
        printCars("Kim",kim);  //+++++NEW
        printcars("Bob",bob);  //+++++NEW

    }

    //+++++NEW All other methods/functions replaced by this one
    public static void printCars(String person, int sales) {
        system.out.println(person + " " + maxsales.substr(sales));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Incrementing by one in Java
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
        
// Incrementing by one
// Printing Horizontally
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    System.out.print(" " + i);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -2):

```
int n = 20;
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.print(" " + i);
}
```